# Django template: access query_set and non-query_set results in same template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a Django app that contains info on schools and states. I want my template to display a list of schools per state and also the name of the state based on the state parameter in the URL. So if a user goes to example.com/vermont/ they will see a list of Vermont schools and a  tag that says they're on the "Vermont" page. I can get the list of schools per state to work, but I can't figure out how to simply list the state name in the h1 tag.

Here is my *models.py*:

```
from django.db import models

class School(models.Model):
school_name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
location_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.school_name
```

Here is my *views.py*:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class StateListView(ListView):
    model = School
    template_name = 'state.html'
    context_object_name = 'schools_by_state'

    def get_queryset(self):
        state_list = self.kwargs['location_state']
        return School.objects.filter(location_state=state_list)
```

And here's my template for *state.html*:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{school.location_state }}</h1> [THIS IS THE LINE THAT DOES NOT WORK]

    {% for school in schools_by_state %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ school.school_name }}</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you need to move the `<h1>` tag within forloop then this should work `<h1>{{ school.location_state }}</h1>` or if you want to show just one state of very first school then you can do `<h1>{{ schools_by_state.0.location_state }}</h1>`??

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks Aamir. I just wanted to show one state so I used: <h1>{{ schools_by_state.0.location_state }}</h1>

Comment: @jbub answer is good. You should follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the school variable never enters the context. You are only setting the schools_by_state to the context.

To add some extra context you need to override the [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/) method. This way you can add the location_state from the url parameter:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(StateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'state': self.kwargs['location_state']})
    return context
```

Then you can use the `{{ state }}` instead of `{{ school.location_state }}` in your template.

Comment: Thank you @jbub for the response and explanation. Much appreciated.